# Local form of a fundamental vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $2l$ on which acts a lie group $G$. Let $X$ be a element in the lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$, we associate to it the vector field $X_M$ defined by $X_M(m)= \frac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=0} e^{-tX}.m$. Let $p$ be a zero of the vector field $X_M$.

In the page 6 of the article [1], the authors say that we can find  some local coordinates $x_1,...,x_{2l}$ around $p$ such that the vector field $X_M$ is linearized:
$$X_M= a_1 \left( x_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} -x_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \right)+\ldots+a_l\left(x_{2l} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2l-1}}-x_{2l-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2l}}\right),$$
$a_1,..,a_l \in \mathbb{R}.$

How can we prove that $X_M$ has the above form locally (around p)?

**References**

[1] Michèle Vergne, "Cohomologie équivariante et théorème de Stokes" (rédigé par Sylvie Paycha) (French)
*Analysis on Lie groups and representation theory. Proceedings of the summer school, Kénitra, France, 1999*, Séminaires et Congrès 7, Paris: Société Mathématique de France (ISBN 2-85629-142-2/pbk), pp. 1-43 (2003), [MR2038647](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2038647), [Zbl 1045.57021](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1045.57021).

Comment: What if $\Bbb R^+$ acts on $\Bbb R^N$ by $t\cdot x = tx$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $M$ admits a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric (which is the case if $G$ is compact) then the exponential map $T_pM\to M$ is locally a diffeomorphism and it is $G$-equivariant. So we just need to understand the action of $G$ on $T_pM$. That action is linear, and preserves the inner product on $T_pM$, so $X$ acts as an element of $so(T_pM)$. Finally, any element of $so(\mathbb R^n)$ can be put to a block-diagonal form (with blocks of size $2\times 2$) by a suitable choice of an orthonormal basis.

If $G$ is not compact, the statement is in general not true.

Comment: could you please elaborate further your answer @user8268. I didn't understand why does it suffices to understand the action of $G$ on $T_pM$, and why how can we construct the local coordinates $x_i$ ?

Comment: you may have to tell me more about what you don's understand: 1. the exp map $T_pM\to M$ is a local diffeo (a diffeo of a neighourhood of $0\in T_pM$ to a neighbourhood of $p\in M$) and $G$-equivariant, therefore, it is enough to understand the action of $G$ (or of $X$) on $T_pM$; 2. the local coordinates on $T_pM$ are linear, given by a suitable orthonormal basis (chosen to simplify $X_{T_pM}$); they then get transferred to $M$ via the local diffeo

Comment: could you please explain it if dimension of M is equal to 2.

Comment: I understand that if choose a suitable orthonormal basis, the matrix which represents the action of $G$ on $T_pM$ is of the form \begin{pmatrix}
0 & - a \\
a & 0 
\end{pmatrix} where $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Suppose $m$ is in a neighborhood of $p$, how can we prove that there exists coordinates $x_1, x_2$ such that $$X_M(m) =a(x_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_1}}\vert_m - x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_2}}\vert_m ).$$

Comment: in dim 2: if $e_1,e_2$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_pM$ then, for a suitable $a\in\mathbb R$, $Xe_1=ae_2$, $Xe_2=-ae_1$, so if $x_1,x_2$ are the corresponding linear coordinates on $T_pM$ then $Xx_1=ax_2$, $Xx_2=-ax_1$, i.e. $X=a(x_1\partial_{x_2}-x_2\partial_{x_1})$. Using exp we then locally identify T_pM$ with $M$.

Comment: I realize that my problem was that I misunderstood what did you mean by $G$ acts on $T_pM$: I was thinking  it is the action coming from the derivative of the action of $G$ on $M$ ,i.e  if $g \in G$ (in our case $g= e^X$), and $a_g : M \rightarrow M, m \longmapsto a_g(m)=g.m$. but after working  with the Lie derivative action and  re-reading your answer and your comments I got it. Thank you very much :)